How to draw a scatter plot with curves using javascript
I'm collecting datapoints, [temperatureC, humidity%, datetime].
I want to plot these in a diagram - with temperature on the x-axis and humidity on the y-axis.
I also want to draw these zones as you can see in this image - especially those three made out of curves.
Mapping these to an approximation - probably some kind of inverse exponential curve is one thing - but I'm specifically looking for any good libraries or charting tools for plain javascript or React that could handle this.
I'll gladly take any tips.


check out the line chart of chart.js
